# Unable to use Microsoft.Web.Helpers in Razor view vbhtml file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, helper

I want to use the Linkshare helper in the Microsoft.Web.Helpers dll. I added the reference to my project but if attempt to use it in the vbhtml file Visual studio underlines it with a blue squiggly and tells me it is inaccessible blah blah. I even added references to those webmatrix dlls as described here: http://hadsy.net/2011/01/19/ASPNETMVC3MicrosoftWebHelpersErrorTheTypeOrNamespaceNameSimpleMembershipProviderCouldNotBeFound.aspx

How can i get the linkshare and other helpers to work?

Comment: Show your code please. Maybe you're just calling the wrong override?

Comment: @marcind, i am typing @LinkShare.GetHtml("My post title is here") 
Linkshare simply does not appear in intellisense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution  is to build the project after adding the assembly reference 
then I was able to use the linkshare helper

Answer (score 0):

You also need to add a reference to the assembly in web.config, under Namespaces

i.e;

```
<pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID">
    <namespaces>
        <clear/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax"/>
        ...
        <add namespace="Microsoft.Web.Helpers"/>
```

Comment: That did not make any difference. Still get the blue squiggle.